# Is there a client-side program to cryptography a HTML page and decode if correct password is writen?

Tags: passwords

I want to know if there is an easy way to do this:

- create a complete HTML page
- cryptography the text content (image is not important)
- ask user some password
- check the password with a cryptographed password `if(hash(userPassword)==hasedPassword)) return true;`
- if the password is correct it will decode it and show the content.

All this in user-side, not server-side. Because this I will use javascript.

Is there any good implementation?

Comment: Down vote :D I really liked the Motox answer. Id didn't is the exatcly, but I can start with it.

Comment: Just to say, I really liked the answer and the discussion with @cpast If someone want to edit this question in future, I will love it. By the way, if someone google this term, they will like the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the text content of the webpage encrypted into HTML5 local storage, IndexedDB or embedded as a hex/base64 string in the web page, then you you could try something like [TripleSec](https://keybase.io/triplesec/) which would take your password, run a PBKDF and decrypt the content.

Or you can use one of the many JavaScript libraries CryptoJS, SJCL etc and do it yourself manually.

You should run the code as a local .html file on the filesystem or in a browser extension. Don't make the mistake of running the JavaScript code served up from the server because your security would only be as strong as the HTTP/HTTPS connection and vulnerable to MITM. Even HTTPS is not secure [against some attackers](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/inside-the-nsa-s-war-on-internet-security-a-1010361.html).

Comment: Great answer!! I am searching all your tips. Just because I am lazy, I am searching a "one page" solution. Like: VAR criptText = #@$@#$; print "Enter the code"; decript(criptText with code); show text as HTML page.

Comment: anyway, I as using this program and will write it myself :D Good start point, anyway.

Comment: SJCL is really good. All the code are in one file, so it is good. I just learn somethings but it is really good for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing this entirely client-side, it's trivial for someone to bypass it. You can't really use the user's computer to keep something from them. That's the problem DRM tries to solve, and even with the full cooperation of the OS to keep things from the user it doesn't work perfectly. Javascript can't do that at all; you need to do encryption on the server side to keep the user from bypassing it.

Comment: Lol, yes, it is easy to bypass. But I just want to do a little more difficult. Maybe 95% of people that will read can't decode it. And this is good for me :D

Comment: Lol, no. I read the algorithm and... no it can be really secure. Don't matter if it is written in javascript. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you *encrypt* it on the client side, it cannot be secure against the client; all they have to do is turn off Javascript and it doesn't get encrypted. If you encrypt on the server side and *decrypt* on the client side, that's a different story (as long as you never send them the plaintext or the password they need to use; if the Javascript has the password they need baked into it, it's again not possible to be secure). That's not entirely client-side, though.

Comment: Lol, what I want to do is no more than use a .zip with password. Everyone can download, but only the one that has the password, can read it. So... I understand your worries. Say the use of a zip with password is a good exaple of what I want to do. :)

Comment: @Rodrigo That'd work fine; I had read your question as "download the page, then encrypt it with JS, then ask for a password to turn into an encryption key and decrypt with JS" (as you'd said "do everything client-side"). This answer is about encrypting client-side; if you don't do that, and derive the decryption key from the password, there's no issue (you have to never send the client the plaintext or key, or else it's easy to bypass the password check).

Comment: So: If you encrypt it client-side, it isn't secure at all (trivial to bypass, as you sent the client the unencrypted text). If you write code along the lines of `key = 0x1234; prompt(password); if isRight(password) decrypt(ciphertext, key)`, it isn't secure at all (as it's trivial to go to the Javascript and get the key from there). If your code is `ciphertext=0x567890; prompt(password); plaintext = decrypt(ciphertext, PBKDF2(password)); if isValid(plaintext) show(plaintext)` it's fine.

Comment: yeah... your last example is what I want to do :D